# Prevent Google indexing an AngularJS route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, seo, robots.txt

Usually, if I didn't want Google to crawl a page, I would add the page to my robots.txt file like so:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my-page
```

To prevent Google indexing that page, I would remove the page from my `sitemap.xml` add the following meta tag to the `<head>` of the page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Now, if I use AngularJS to handle all routing for a single page application, how do stop Google indexing and/or crawling a route? Angular brings content in the ng-view for each route, so information in the `<head>` remains the same on every route. I don't think I can add the meta tag in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your root module is placed on the `<html>` tag (`<html ng-app="myApp">`), you can modify all properties in the `<head>`. That allows you to dynamically set the robots `<meta>` for each page. You can do that with the [$routeChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess) event in your root module. If you are using ui-router, you could set a 'data' property on the route which you can read in with every state change. You could also use $rootScope to update this value from other modules, but it's not a good practice. The best way would be to broadcast a change to your root module from child controllers/directives.

I have an example that changes the page `<title>` dynamically, but it is a bit more complex because this app is being bootstrapped manually. However, imagine there is a ng-app="" and ng-controller="" directive on the `<html>` tag.

Here is the state change event: https://github.com/danmindru/angular-boilerplate-study/blob/master/src/app/_app-main/_app-main.controller.js#L14-L24

Here is the listener for the broadcast: https://github.com/danmindru/angular-boilerplate-study/blob/master/src/app/_app-main/_app-main.controller.js#L38-L40

Here's how the broadcast is triggered: https://github.com/danmindru/angular-boilerplate-study/blob/master/src/app/profile-feature/customer-page/customer-page.controller.js#L12

Here's the `<title>` binding: https://github.com/danmindru/angular-boilerplate-study/blob/master/src/index.html#L4

However, Google is not that good at reading these properties, so you would have to use a pre-rendering service to make sure the googlebot will parse `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` instead of something like `<meta name="robots" content="{{index}}">`.

Comment: Thank you. My apps already pre-render for SEO and I always put the root module on the html tag so this should work fine.